# Can't test effects of resolved promise

Tags: javascript, testing, promise, mocha.js, sinon

I have the following code in user:

```
 import { redirectTo } from 'urlUtils';
 export function create(user) {
    api.postUser(user).then((response) => {
      redirectTo(response.userUrl);
    })
 }
```

And I have the following test:

```
import * as api from 'api'
import * as user from 'user'

sinon.stub(api, 'postUser').returns(
  Promise.resolve({ userUrl: 'a-url' })
);
sinon.spy(urlUtils, 'redirectTo');
const userData = {id: 2};

user.create(userData);
expect(api.postUser.calledWith(userData)).toBe(true);  // This passes
expect(urlUtils.redirectTo.calledOnce).toBe(true); // This fails
```

I have been able to test it on the browser, and the redirect is happening. What am I missing here? I have stubbed the request call to resolve the promise synchronously, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: a promise is asynchronous - you're not waiting for it to resolve

Comment: But I am stubing and resolving the Promise, as you can see in: `sinon.stub(api, 'poserUser').returns(
  Promise.resolve({ userUrl: 'a-url' })
);`

Comment: but, promises are still asynchronous

Comment: so, what is the best way to test these scenarios?

Comment: `sinon.stub(api, 'poserUser')` is it a typo? Shouldn't be 'postUser'?

Comment: yes - edited. @strah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Promises are asynchronous, so when you're doing `expect(urlUtils.redirectTo.calledOnce).toBe(true)` the promise hasn't been resolved yet.

The easiest way to get around it is to wrap that expectation in a short timeout and then use whatever utility the testing framework you're using provides to signal that an asynchronous test is complete. Something like this:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  expect(urlUtils.redirectTo.calledOnce).toBe(true);
  done();
}, 5);
```

Another, nicer solution is to actually use the promise that your stub returns. First, keep a reference to that promise:

Replace:

```
sinon.stub(api, 'postUser').returns(
  Promise.resolve({ userUrl: 'a-url' })
);
```

with:

```
const postUserPromise = Promise.resolve({ userUrl: 'a-url' });
sinon.stub(api, 'postUser').returns(postUserPromise);
```

then write your expectation like this:

```
postUserPromise.then(() => {
  expect(urlUtils.redirectTo.calledOnce).toBe(true);
  done();
});
```

---

`done()` is the function most test frameworks (at least Jasmine and Mocha as far as I know) provide to signal that an asynchronous test is completed. You get it as the first argument to the function your test is defined in and by specifying it in your function signature you're telling the test framework that your test is asynchronous.

Examples:

```
it("is a synchronous test, completed when test function returns", () => {
  expect(true).to.equal(true);
});

it("is an asynchronous test, done() must be called for it to complete", (done) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    expect(true).to.equal(true);
    done();
  }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: I am stubing and resolving the promise, as you can see in: `sinon.stub(api, 'poserUser').returns(
  Promise.resolve({ userUrl: 'a-url' })
);`

Comment: @HommerSmith A promise is still asynchronous even if it resolves "immediately", i.e. the invokation of the callbacks are deferred until the thread becomes idle

Comment: doesn't that become really bad in terms of adding time for test suite?

Comment: @HommerSmith We're only talking about of a few milliseconds, it's only to defer the expectation to make sure it's called after the already deferred promise callback. There is a better alternative, but it's a bit more complex, I'll amend my answer with that.

Comment: `done()` is the function your test framework provides for asynchronous tests, it's what you use to tell the test framework that the test is complete and that it should proceed with the next test. I added a description in my answer. This may work different depending in various test frameworks. I can't tell from your code which framework you're using.

Comment: Mikael, thanks a lot for the explanation. Somehow it seems that the expectations I write inside the postUserPromise.then(...) don't get executed. I have writen expect(false).toBe(true) and is still green. Any thoughts? If I put console.logs inside, they are rendered, so not sure what's going on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144921/discussion-between-hommer-smith-and-mikael-lennholm).